# pysnmp how to load custom MIB modules which are in asn.1 format

Tags: python, mib, pysnmp

I am having trouble in figuring out how to load custom MIBs which with .txt extensions using `pysnmp` module

This is what I am doing currently

```
b = builder.MibBuilder()
compiler.addMibCompiler(b, sources=[mib_location])
```

mib_location is folder on which all my MIBs are located. something like `file:///<my_folder>`

But still I am not able to load these MIBs.

I am thinking that may be I'll have to specify that my MIBs have an extension of .txt but not sure where.

Answer (score 0):

MIB files should be found by MIB module name without any extension or with .txt one.

Here is an [example](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/v3arch/asyncore/manager/cmdgen/mib-tweaks.html#walk-agent-and-resolve-variables-at-mib) that should work out of the box.

If not, try adding:

```
from pysmi import debug
debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('all'))
```

To your script and watch stdout -- pysmi will report where exactly it is looking for MIB files. Hope it gives you enough information to figure out what goes wrong.